# Efficent way to get all keys in unorganized array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I want to get all the keys in an array of objects. Initially I just grabbed the first object in the array and used:

```
var keys = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
```

But when I looked closer at the data I noticed that the first row didn't contain all the needed keys. In the following example the third item contains all the keys but you might have a case where getting all the keys requires combining multiple objects.

```
var tableData = [
  { first:"jeff", last:"doe", phone: "2891" },
  { first:"sarah", phone:"this", county: "usa" }
  { first:"bob", last:"brown", county: "usa", phone: "23211" }
];
```

How can I get all the unique keys in an array of objects that will be efficent at large scale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get desired result.

```js
var array = [
  { first:"jeff", last:"doe", phone: "2891" },
  { first:"sarah", phone:"this", county: "usa" },
  { first:"bob", last:"brown", county: "usa", phone: "23211" }
];

var keys = [...new Set(array.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r = r.concat(Object.keys(e));
  return r;
}, []))];

console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 3):

You might simply do as follows;

```
var array = [
  { first:"jeff", last:"doe", phone: "2891" },
  { first:"sarah", phone:"this", county: "usa" },
  { first:"bob", last:"brown", county: "usa", phone: "23211" }
];

var result = array.reduce((p,o) => Object.assign(p,Object.keys(o)),[]);
console.log(result);
```

As per a very rightful comment here is my the next solution;

```js
var array = [
  { first:"jeff", last:"doe", phone: "2891", moron: "me"},
  { first:"sarah", phone:"this", county: "usa" },
  { first:"bob", last:"brown", county: "usa", phone: "23211" }
];

var result = array.reduce((p,o) => p.concat(Object.keys(o).filter(k => !p.includes(k))),[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The result only displays the keys of the last object!

Comment: @Peter Leger You are right... Shamefully I did something new.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) :

```js
var arr = [
  { first:"jeff", last:"doe", phone: "2891", something: "4" },
  { first:"sarah", phone:"this", county: "usa" },
  { first:"bob", last:"brown", county: "usa", phone: "23211", lastrow: "lr" }
];

var set = new Set();
arr.map(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(el => {
    set.add(el);
  });
});
var res = [...set];
console.log(res);
```

I've tested the `console time` in the chrome browser from the code above with the code from [@Nenad Vracar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40094316/3589620) and [@Redu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40094678/3589620) :

```
var array = [
    { first:"jeff", last:"doe", phone: "2891", something: "4" },
    { first:"sarah", phone:"this", county: "usa" },
    { first:"bob", last:"brown", county: "usa", phone: "23211", lastrow: "lr" }
];

function f1(arr) { // Peter Leger
    var set = new Set();
    arr.map(obj => {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(el => {
            set.add(el);
        });
    });
    var res = [...set];
    return res; 
} 

function f2(arr) { // Nenad Vracar
    var keys = [...new Set(arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
        r = r.concat(Object.keys(e));
        return r;
    }, []))];
    return keys;
}

function f3(arr) { // Redu
    var result = arr.reduce((p,o) => p.concat(Object.keys(o).filter(k => !p.includes(k))),[]);
    return result;
}

var iterations = 1000000;
console.time('Function f1');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    f1(array);
};
console.timeEnd('Function f1')

console.time('Function f2');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    f2(array);
};
console.timeEnd('Function f2')

console.time('Function f3');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    f3(array);
};
console.timeEnd('Function f3')
```

with the following results :

**First result:**

- Function f1: 6375.193ms
- Function f2: 6309.516ms
- Function f3: 6756.946ms

**Second result:**

- Function f1: 6152.040ms
- Function f2: 8004.565ms
- Function f3: 6885.656ms

**Third result:**

- Function f1: 5918.497ms
- Function f2: 8136.073ms
- Function f3: 7111.273ms